# Textbox doesn't return current value in Visual C#

Tags: c#, textbox

I'm trying to put the current integer value of a textbox immediately into an integer, but with following code it seems that I'm always 1 step behind :

```
private void txtMemoryLocation_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    // Only allow numeric value
    if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar))
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }

    if (txtMemoryLocation.Text != "")
    {
        nLocation = int.Parse(txtMemoryLocation.Text.Trim());
    }
}
```

I always start with a number 1 in the textbox, when I change the "1" to "10", my nLocation changes to 1, when I enter "100", nLocation becomes 10.

What is going on?

Comment: What is the value of nLocation when you first start up the program and the number 1 is in the textbox? The event is fired when you perform a keypress while the element is in focus, but the value of the textbox is updated AFTER the event is fired, meaning the value of txtMemoryLocation.Text still holds the previous value.

Answer (score 0):

Hook the TextChanged event instead and do your parsing there. When KeyDown, KeyPress, and KeyUp fire, the textbox still hasn't had a chance to accept the new character.

Alternatively you could including the newly pressed key my modifying your existing function like this:

```
private void txtMemoryLocation_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    // Only allow numeric value
    if (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar))
    {
        e.Handled = true;
    }

    if (txtMemoryLocation.Text != "")
    {
        nLocation = int.Parse(txtMemoryLocation.Text.Trim() + e.KeyChar);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the KeyPress and KeyDown event will call before add new pressed char **TextBox.Text** and if **e.handle** is false the new char will add to **TextBox.Text** and **TextBox.TextChanged** will called.
 you can do this like me

> Note : at first add TextChanged metod to  txtMemoryLocation.TextChanged

```
private void txtMemoryLocation_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    e.Handled = (!char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) && !char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar));
}
private void TextChanged(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
    nLocation = int.Parse(txtMemoryLocation.Text.Trim());
}
```